# Chrome Error code: ERR_UNSAFE_PORT - Bottle hello world app not showing in browser

Tags: python, port, bottle

EDIT:

I looked at the chrome error code and it said: `Error code: ERR_UNSAFE_PORT`. I changed the port to 6001 and it works fine - why would that be, is 6000 generally a port you can't use for local development for some reason?

I've built the hello world app (I've called it app.py) like so:

```
from bottle import route, run

@route('/hello')
def hello():
    return "<h1>Hello World!</h1>"

run(host='localhost', port=6000, debug=True)
```

And I'm in a virtualenv setup with app.py in the same directory level as bin/, include/, and lib/ folders from the virtual environment. The file bottle.py is inside bin/ When I run `python app.py`, I get this output:

```
Bottle v0.12.3 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://localhost:6000/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.
```

But when I go to `http://localhost:6000/hello` I get "This website is not available" in Chrome. Have I structured my files wrong somehow? Thanks!

Comment: Your code works in my environment.

Comment: This doesn't help, but you shouldn't put your files in the bin/ or /include directories. The virtualenvironment directories are not for your source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not your app, it's Chrome.

From https://superuser.com/a/188012/220530:

> Right Click on Chrome shortcut >> Properties >>
>
> Then Append --explicitly-allowed-ports=xxx to shortcut target
>
> Example:
>
> C:\Documents and Settings\User\Local Settings\Application
> Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
> --explicitly-allowed-ports=6666

Comment: not a solution on mac

Answer (score 1):

> I looked at the chrome error code and it said: Error code:
>   ERR_UNSAFE_PORT. I changed the port to 6001 and it works fine - why
>   would that be, is 6000 generally a port you can't use for local
>   development for some reason?

THere is a list of unsafe port for chrome:

https://superuser.com/a/188070/565230

The reason it's called unsafe is not because it's unsafe to Chrome, it's because it's unsafe to those services, where an attacker may try to use Chrome as a proxy to attacking services on those ports.

https://superuser.com/a/465228/565230

Among the ports listed, 6000 is the port used by X11.

Answer (score 0):

For **windows 8.1**,

> Right Click on Chrome shortcut >> Properties >>
>
> Then Append --explicitly-allowed-ports=xxx to shortcut target
>
> Example:
>
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
>   --explicitly-allowed-ports=6666